# Problems with configure tomcat 7.0.37 with eclipse juno on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have some problems with configure tomcat 7 with eclipse juno. I was installed jdk 1.7 update 17 and tomcat 7.0.32. When I try define new server what has used tomcat 7. I can't add it in define server part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maybe this blog will be useful for you:
http://hariprasad.info/cannot-create-a-server-using-the-selected-type-eclipse-tomcat/